# Extract clusters (groups) from distance matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I had a binary matrix that I turned into a distance matrix in order to create clusters of the items in it. My question is how can I group the resulted distance matrix into clusters. For example, I would have something like a data.frame with clusters as columns and each item from the distance matrix belongs to one cluster.

Is that possible?
Below is the distance matrix I created.

```
       one    three   two
one     0      1.0    1.0
three   1      0.0    0.5
two     1      0.5    0.0
```

I know that I can represent as a hierarchial cluster, but I do not know how to extract the clusters from it.

Comment: see `?cutree` for more details on how to extract groups following hierarchical clustering.

Comment: And do consider increasing the size of the example. It is possible to create one that is so minimal as to be degenerate.

Comment: In addition to hierarchical clustering, you can also take a look at several other clustering methods that require you to specify the number of clusters beforehand. The functions for these methods usually output the clusters directly to a `list` or a similar structure. k-means is one popular example of such a cluster analysis, but there are dozens of others.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. When I use the cutree to extract clusters from the hclust. I get a new matrix with the clusters as columns.
Now, I want to extract the first cluster from the cutree, how do I got by doing that?

the output from the cutree is similar to this.
`
           1   2   3 
    one    1   1   1
    two    1   2   2
    three  1   3   2
`